# Android: ImageView that extends onTouchEvent for Drag

Tags: android, imageview, drag, extend, touch-event

I wrote a simple cards game where the user plays his card 
doing TAP on one of the three imageviews (the cards)
I'd like to add the possibility of playing the card
by dragging the ImageView on the "table"
(the table is another layout or simply another part of the screen).

I tryed to use the techinc indicated at
http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/
but as it uses AbsoluteLayout, it introduces a lot of limitations
on my current layout, more it requires adjustments depending
to the device screen resolution where the app runs.
I'd like to avoid this continue using
-if possibile- the RelativeLayout.
Maybe the starting point is extenting the ImageView
adding the onTouch support but i couldn't reproduce
the wished effect (drag)
Any idea or suggestion or sample code?
Thanks!

Just to give an idea, this is the draft of layout.
The 3 cards below should be moved via drag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/player_cards_layout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#55335588"
    android:layout_above="@+id/player_cards_layout" 
>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_pc_card_1"
        android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/player_cards_layout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#336699"
>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_user_card_1"
        android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
    />      
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_user_card_2" 
        android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_user_card_1"
    />      
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_user_card_3" 
        android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_user_card_2"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I definitively solved my problems changing the approach and start using the methods provided by Blahti. Thanks to him!

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

here is nice example from [link](https://myandroidwidgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DragDrop). i hope this will help you.

**res/layout/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="Drag Me"></Button>
</FrameLayout>
```

**src/com/beanie/example/Home.java**

```
package com.beanie.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

public class Home extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private final static int START_DRAGGING = 0;
private final static int STOP_DRAGGING = 1;

private Button btn;
private FrameLayout layout;
private int status;
private LayoutParams params;

private ImageView image;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
    // layout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(this);

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        status = START_DRAGGING;
        image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageBitmap(btn.getDrawingCache());
        layout.addView(image, params);
    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        status = STOP_DRAGGING;
        Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
    } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
            System.out.println("Dragging");
            image.setPadding((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY(), 0, 0);
            image.invalidate();
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou so much for your fast reply! This is a good starting point. 
There are few things I need to clarify: after releasing the finger (ACTION_UP) the button is not moveable anymore. 
Moreover, I need to have more than one element moveable a the same time (see my application draft layout): in the example there is only one and i can't make needed changes :-( I'll appreciate suggestions to improve that code.